# Is there an R function to deal with overflow calls in a call center?

Tags: r, queue, priority-queue

I am trying to model a system as follows:

There are two different types of calls with arrival rates lambda1 and lambda2 and answered by to different skilled agents S1 and S2.(S1=S2=1).
The processing time is mu1 for calls of Type 1 dealt by S1 and mu2 for calls of Type 2 dealt by S2.

If the server S1 in system 1 is busy (so the new incoming calls have to wait in a queue), then the waiting call is redirected to server S2 in system 2 and are completed with a processing time mu3.
Server S2 answers first to calls coming from system 1, when the queue in system 1 is empty, then S2 answers to calls coming from system 2.

I tried multiple times to model the environment but this is everything that I could come up with:

```
## Create arrivals
## rho = traffic load (0:1)
rho = 0.5
inter_arrival1 = rexp(500, 1.3*rho)
inter_arrival2 = rexp(500, 0.4*rho)
mu1 = 1
mu2= 1
mu3= 0.5
m = 1 # number of servers

## Queue model System 1
m.queue <- trajectory() %>%
  seize("server", amount=1) %>%
  timeout(function() rexp(1, mu1)) %>%
  release("server", amount=1)

mean(mmc.df.arr$activity_time)
mmc.env <- simmer() %>%
  add_resource("server", capacity=1, queue_size=Inf) %>%
  add_generator("arrival", m.queue, function() rexp(500, 1.3*rho)) %>%
  run(2000)


mmc.df.res <- get_mon_resources(mmc.env)
mmc.df.arr <- get_mon_arrivals(mmc.env)
mmc.df.arr
mmc.df.res

#Data dataframe system1
system1 <- data.frame("Call number"=(1:length(mmc.df.res$time)),
                      "Arrival time"=mmc.df.res$time,
                      "Arrival rate"= (system1$Call.number/system1$Arrival.time),
                      "Expected start"=mmc.df.arr$start_time,
                      "Expected end" = mmc.df.arr$end_time,
                      "Processing time"= mmc.df.arr$activity_time,
                      "Waiting time" = mmc.df.arr$start_time-mmc.df.res$time,
                      "Number of calls in the system" = mmc.df.res$system,
                      "Time spent in the system"=system1$Expected.end-system1$Arrival.time)

## Queue model System 2
m.queue2 <- trajectory() %>%
  seize("server", amount=1) %>%
  timeout(function() rexp(1, mu2)) %>%
  release("server", amount=1)


mmc.env2 <- simmer() %>%
  add_resource("server", capacity=1, queue_size=Inf) %>%
  add_generator("arrival", m.queue, function() rexp(500, 0.4*rho)) %>%
  run(2000)

mmc.df.res2 <- get_mon_resources(mmc.env2)
mmc.df.arr2 <- get_mon_arrivals(mmc.env2)
```

I'm quite new with R so I'm struggling to find a way to identify the calls waiting in the queue of system 1 and redirect them to the agent in system 2 with priority. I would be really grateful if someone could suggest me a way out of it.

Comment: Hi @Luna can you please share the packages used to run the code

Comment: Hi @Isa, the package is "simmer" and "simmer.plot"

Answer (score 0):

Have you figured out the solution for this?
I couldn't run your code. system1 data frame could not be built (and it's not used later in the code anyways).

Nonetheless, I doubt if the structure you've set up can work since you're isolating the two systems whereas based on what you described they can interact.

Even if the two sets of calls are different they still can run through one simulation environment and you'd determine which type they are using an attribute.

Here is how I dealt with adding overflow logic to a call centre (with different details). My two sets of vendors are similar to your two sets of agents but my vendors can answer any calls. You'd need to distribute some calls to one vendor and some two another since your calls are different.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73163307/9249121